# Customize the Error Message MVC for an invalid DateTime in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble specifying the error message for the validation of a DateTime input value using data annotations in my model. I would really like to use the proper DateTime validator (as opposed to Regex, etc).

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "A valid Date or Date and Time must be entered eg. January 1, 2014 12:00AM")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I still get the default date validation message of "The field Date must be a date."

Am I missing something?

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1882022.aspx/1

Comment: Facing the same issue in 2016, you would have thought that they have solved by now ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have one dirty solution.

Create custom model binder:

```
public class CustomModelBinder<T> : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if(value != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            T temp = default(T);
            try
            {
                temp = ( T )TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T)).ConvertFromString(value.AttemptedValue);
            }
            catch
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "A valid Date or Date and Time must be entered eg. January 1, 2014 12:00AM");
                bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);
            }

            return temp;
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

And then in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new CustomModelBinder<DateTime>());
```

Comment: I don't think x2 suggested a dirty solution. Rather I believe mvc team did a dirty solution by hard-coding the error message. Giving the message in resource file as per @cilerler is okay, still the developer lacks the freedom to write model specific custom message. It really sucks! So I go with x2 to override the DefaultModelBinder with a CustomModelBinder, with some changes to pick the ValueError message from bindingContext.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues and now I can write model specific custom messages by adding an attribute AdditionalMetadata("ValueError","write d message you wish")]

Comment: I agree with you eka. In hindsight, I see this is a very acceptable answer.

Comment: Most acceptable answer i found for this crappy situation so far.

Answer (score 39):

Add the following keys into Application_Start() at Global.asax

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "YourResourceName";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "YourResourceName";
```

Create **YourResourceName.resx** inside **App_GlobalResources** folder and add the following keys

- **FieldMustBeDate** The field {0} must be a date.
- **FieldMustBeNumeric** The field {0} must be a number.
- **PropertyValueInvalid** The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
- **PropertyValueRequired** A value is required.

Comment: This is the cleanest answer and does the job for me in MVC4.  I've now got [Display], [Remote], data type and self-validating error messages being translated by the one set of resource files.  Anyone know of an easy way to easily translate the form headings?

Comment: For some reason I cannot get the correct translation for  PropertyValueInvalid . It always shows the default one, while the other labels show the translated resource...

Comment: @user1073075 please create a new question with your code. if you may provide your question link here, I may look into that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26890014/customised-error-messages-are-not-translated-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this when the resources are in a separate assembly?

Comment: Sadly this only works on a global scope. Is there any way to do the same thing for an individual field?

Answer (score 16):

I found one simple workaround.

You can leave your model untouched.

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Then override the 'data-val-date' attribute in a view.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    data_val_date = "Custom error message."
})
```

Or if you want to parameterize your messages, you can just use static function `String.Format`:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    data_val_date = String.Format("The field '{0}' must be a valid date.",  
                                    Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date))
})
```

Similar with resources:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new
{
    @class = "form-control",
    data_val_date = String.Format(Resources.ErrorMessages.Date,  
                                   Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date))
})
```

Comment: Interesting workaround. It's a bit hacky though since your embedding this code in specific views. It might work in a pinch, but I'd generally avoid this.

Comment: I would avoid all the solutions in here, but MVC team created this unfortunate situation and for me it was the fastest/easiest quick fix even though I don't like it. Global scope does not work for my project, sadly. They should check if you've already put a "DataType" data annotation and remove their default validation in this case, and not give you that weird error : "Validation type names in unobtrusive client validation rules must be unique.". That way, you can put your own messages.

Comment: Thank you! I feel like I'd tried just about everything under the sun to work around the lack of support for ErrorMessage in DataType. I agree with the other comments that it's slightly hacky in that it is specific to views, but I'm needing this for lack of HTML5 input date client support (looking at you Firefox). Thank you, this has saved me from spending even more time, and possibly saved my sanity too.

Answer (score 1):

I got around this issue by modifying the error in the ModelState collection at the start of my action method. Something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        ModelState myFieldState = ModelState["MyField"];
        DateTime value;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(myFieldState.Value.AttemptedValue, out value))
        {
            myFieldState.Errors.Clear();
            myFieldState.Errors.Add("My custom error message");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Putting this logic inside controller actions doesn't sound like a very good solution to me.

Comment: I've yet to see a "good" solution to this, so I guess we are left to pick the best of a bad bunch. This does have the benefit over the top voted answer of being able to apply to only one field in your site rather than globally changing the validation for all date fields.

Comment: I don't like this solution, but it is the best I could find ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a regular expression annotation like

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}(?:\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})?")]
public string Date { get; set; }
```

or [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390403/datetime-date-and-hour-validation-with-data-annotation)

Comment: I'd like to avoid a regular expression annotation so I can still have all the flexibility of the default DateTime input validation/parsing.. i.e 2014-01-01, 2014-01-01 12:00, Jan 1 2014, January 1, 2014 12:00 AM, or any other valid permutation

Comment: Did you check that link then?

Comment: I was able to get custom validation attribute working for validation, but still no luck overriding the default error message. I even tried manually setting this.ErrorMessage from within the IsValid() function, but it says "The value 'xx' is not valid for Date".

Comment: Validation is happening on the model data, unfortunately this message is thrown right from the DefaultModelBinder (well before the validation) either you have to go with @x2 or cilerler