# Customised error messages are not translated in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, global-asax

I want to translate the validation message "The field Date must be a date."

I've added the following keys into Application_Start() at Global.asax

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "ModelBinders";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "ModelBinders";
```

I've created ModelBinders.resx, ModelBinders.nl.resx, ModelBinders.fr.resx in App_GlobalResources.

I've added the following string resources (or translations) in the .resx files:

> ```
> Name                   Value
> ====                   =====
> FieldMustBeDate        The field {0} must be a date.
> FieldMustBeNumeric     The field {0} must be a number.
> PropertyValueInvalid   The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.
> PropertyValueRequired  A value is required.
> ```

When I submit a string for a date, I will receive the translation for "FieldMustBeDate". When I submit an invalid date (for example "01/01/201a") I receive the untranslated message for "PropertyValueInvalid" that is defined in the default ModelBinders.resx , instead of the translation... How can I show the correct translation for PropertyValueInvalid?

Comment: Can you post your model?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll explain how I specific client messages. First, in the model you set the resource:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelBinders), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
    [Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelBinders))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Second, in the the controller you overwrite thread culture, I get that from a route, for example in the Initialize method:

```
    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        string cultureInfo = requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("cultureInfo");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureInfo);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureInfo);
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
    }
```

[image: Client messages in English]

[image: Client messages in Spanish]

It is important that resources are properly formatted: ModelBinders.resx, ModelBinders.es-ES.resx, ModelBinders.en-US.resx ... And nothing else, It works for me well. I hope this approach will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I did the same without overriding the controller's initialize method. Adding that code made it work for me.

Comment: make sure you do not add the code for setting the threads language into an action filters OnActionExecuting method - it wont work!