# MVC Serverside Validation not always localized, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, localization

I have the following properties in my View Model:

```
public decimal Credit { get; set; }

[EmailAddress]
public string TestEmail { get; set; }
```

And I got these 2 error messages on **Serverside** validation, using `@Html.ValidationSummary()`:

- The value '97,50 €' is not valid for Credit.
- Das Feld TestEmail enthält keine gültige E-Mail-Adresse.

The second one is perfect translated using the `[EmailAddress]` Attribute. However the first one, is still in english. Why?

I have googled a bit but every solution is talking about customizing the Validation-messages. What I want is the default Validation-message, but translated to my Culture, like the `[EmailAddress]` Attribute.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE"/>
```

So how can I make the message *The value '97,50 €' is not valid for Credit.* be translated to another language?

I have not included the client side validation scripts.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but it worth checking, did you put it in the correct web.config ? (There are two of them).

Comment: I have put it into the rootlevel `web.config`. All deeper configs have not this value. @OrelEraki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Messages.resx` in the folder `App_GlobalResources`.
Add the following line:

> PropertyValueInvalid | Der Wert "{0}" ist für das Feld "{1}" nicht erlaubt.

Then point to the `Messages.resx` in you `Application_Start()`

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Messages";
```

Some others which might be helpfull:

> FieldMustBeDate | Das Feld "{0}" ist kein gültiges Datum.
>
> FieldMustBeNumeric | Das Feld "{0}" ist keine gültige Zahl.
>
> PropertyValueRequired | Das Feld "{0}" ist erforderlich.

Comment: But why does `[EmailAdress]` work? Is .NET realy only partitial localized?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt that just a bug in MVC default localization. You only find one, but there [are others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377131/customize-the-error-message-mvc-for-an-invalid-datetime-in-asp-net-mvc4).

Comment: Strange. Didn't expect that there are bugs in basic things like that in such a battle tested framework. @teovankot

Comment: I didn't tried it already, but I think we need to define [`DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17901575/2441442). If so, I think this should be added to the solution for future readers.