# DateTime Regex Validator

Tags: c#, jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want a regex which works for following criteria for a DateTime:

1. DateTime must be in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
2. If only date is entered in MM/dd/yyyy then also it is valid.
3. In date month and day must be in two digit.

I tried following regular expression but it don't work for some dates like: **12/12/2012**

```
[RegularExpression(@"^((((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?2[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9]))))[\-\/\s]?\d{2}(([02468][048])|([13579][26])))|(((((0?[13578])|(1[02]))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0?[469])|(11))[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(30)))|(0?2[\-\/\s]?((0?[1-9])|(1[0-9])|(2[0-8]))))[\-\/\s]?\d{2}(([02468][1235679])|([13579][01345789]))))(\s(((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\:([0-5][0-9])((\s)|(\:([0-5][0-9])\s))([AM|PM|am|pm]{2,2})))?$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid date.")]
```

Comment: That's **the regex**... Why don't you validate the date via parsing?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov, how? i dont know that method?

Comment: As example: [DateTime (date and hour) validation with Data Annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390403/datetime-date-and-hour-validation-with-data-annotation). Btw, your regex accepts `12/12/2012` without problem: http://regex101.com/r/mQ8qA4

Comment: why don't you use `DateTime.TryParse`. That way you make sure your really accept only valid datetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on regex solution, I modified yours a bit (to restrict it to rules you provided):

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0[13578])|(?:1[02]))\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[01])))|(?:(?:(?:0[469])|11)\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|30))|(?:02\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9]))))\/\d{2}(?:(?:[02468][048])|(?:[13579][26])))|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0[13578])|(?:1[02]))\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[01])))|(?:(?:(?:0[469])|(?:11))\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:30)))|(?:02\/(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-9])|(?:2[0-8]))))\/\d{2}(?:(?:[02468][1235679])|(?:[13579][01345789]))))(?:\s(?:(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\:(?:[0-5][0-9])(?:\:(?:[0-5][0-9])\s))(?:AM|PM|am|pm))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eO3wX0)**

Slightly simplified regex (correctly validates dates in 0000-9999 range):

```
^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])\/(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]))|(?:(?:0[469]|11)\/(?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:02\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))\/\d{4}|02\/29\/(?:(?:\d{2}(?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?:(?:[02468][048])|[13579][26])00))(?:\s(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])\:[0-5][0-9]\:[0-5][0-9]\s(?:AM|PM|am|pm))?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tX9eO8)**

Comment: whats difference between dark blue and light blue?

Comment: @Dhwani These are just alternate colors so you don't think that it is a single match.

Comment: +1 for changing the color of the matrix, I was getting tired of black and green. :)

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov okie. will d{2} take year length of 2 digit?

Comment: @Dhwani Please, clarify your comment. In your original regex and in regexes I posted `d{2}` is used only as century.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I mean century of last 2 digit? or 4 dgit?

Comment: @Dhwani Century consists of first 2 digits. Full year is always 4 digits (even in case of `0000`).

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov I want 4 digit full year.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov last one regex?

Comment: @Dhwani Both of them. But last one is valid for all leap years. The first one (made by cleaning of yours) has problems with `1900`, `2100` years (not leap because divisible by 100 and not divisible by 400).