# ASP MVC data validation model attributes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am using data annotation attributes to provide metainfo for client side validation. The following code adds `data-val-date` attribute correctly to the corresponding html input element:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }
```

I have date *and* time input fields too and I would like to apply different validation rules there. However adding different DataType value changes nothing in the rendered input element:

```
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }
```

rendered in the *very* same way I mean it renders also a `data-val-date` attribute so at client side the two kinds of input validation is indistinguishable.

As a bonus using

```
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? TestDate { get; set; }
```

renders *no* `data-val` attribute.
Then what's the use of the different DataType attributes?. And more importantly, how can I correctly render a `data-val-datetime` and `data-val-time` attributes? (what I am going to handle in a custom way at client side using jQuery validation)

Comment: I think it's better to use regular expression validation `[RegularExpression("pattern")]`

Comment: I believe the answer to this question will hep you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390403/datetime-date-and-hour-validation-with-data-annotation

Comment: @MikeDebela: A big problem with using regex validation for a scenario like this is localization. Date/time formats vary wildly across the globe, and trying to accomodate every potential input in a regex is a bit of a nightmare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `DataType` attributes is, in part, to inform things like `Html.EditorFor` what template to use. However, if you're simply calling something like `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestDate)` in your view, then the `DataType` begins to have more limited utility.

The client-side validation is a separate library that MVC merely utilizes. As you can see at the [documentation for that library](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-list-of-built-in-validation-methods), there is no "datetime" validator, only "date" and "dateISO". Also conspicuously missing is "time".

The best thing you could actually do here, though, is to utilize the HTML5 input types, as not only will they validate proper date/time/datetime inputs, but they should automatically localize to the user's preferred format (assuming the browser follows the specs in this regard).

To fully utilize your `DataType` attribute, you should render your inputs with `Html.EditorFor`, which will include the proper HTML5 input type by default based on the `DataType`.

Short of that, you can specify the type manually:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TestDate, new { type = "date" })
```